# After updating to 21.10, upload always defaults to the Home folder

Tags: home, upload

So, ever since I updated ubuntu to v21.10, no matter which browser I use, when I click on the attachment or upload buttons - anything - the "Open Files" window defaults to the Home folder. It used to stay in the folder that was used for the last upload.

In the screenshot, you can also see that the "Open Files" is not in focus, as if it's in the "Always on top" state. Previously, it was in bright white letters, so you see it's the window that's on top. Now, it's grayed out until you start navigating through the file selection screen.

[image: grayed out when clicking on the "upload" button]

And here's how it used to be (just notice the difference, it's kind of hard to explain):

[image: in focus upload modal screen]

Thank you in advance!